# Return response after Volley queue is empty

Tags: android, mobile, network-programming, android-volley

The ArrayList I am trying to return is empty even though the objects gets added in the onResponse method.
I am suspecting that the method getEvents returns the empty ArrayList before the objects actually gets added to the ArrayList.
Are there a method to call after the queue have processed the request?

```
public class CustomRestRequestArray {
Authorizer authorizer;
ArrayList<Event> events;

public ArrayList<Event> getEvents(Context context, String url) throws JSONException {
   events = new ArrayList<>();
    authorizer = new Authorizer(context);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonEvents = response.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i=0; i< jsonEvents.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject obj = jsonEvents.getJSONObject(i);
                            Event event = new Event(
                                    obj.getInt("id"),
                                    obj.getString("name"),
                                    obj.getString("description"),
                                    obj.getString("start"),
                                    obj.getString("end"),
                                    obj.getBoolean("isPublic"),
                                    obj.getString("address")
                            );
                            events.add(event);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + authorizer.getToken());
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(getRequest);
    return events;
}
```

}

Comment: "Are there a method to call after the queue have processed the request?" - Yes. The `onResponse()` method is called when the request completes. Don't try to return `events` from `getEvents()`. Just do whatever you need to do with `events` at the end of `onResponse()`, after the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, and for the suggestions of other questions Mike.